# Can anyone identify this wheel?

Tags: road-bike, wheels, identify-this-bike, rims, gravel

I have been trying to identify the front wheel on my all-road/gravel bike, which was bought second hand (the original wheels were replaced).

The only distinctive feature is a logo, accompanying the number "29", on the rim – see photos below.

Does anyone recognise this particular wheel or the brand's logo?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The logo is from a Carrera (Halfords) bike, so the wheel will have been on a Carrera originally.

You can google the Carrera logo and see that the C is styled in the same way on their full logo.

The 29 is simply referring to the wheel size, a mtb '29er' which has the same ETRTO rim diameter as a typical road/gravel bike, though widths can vary.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering why I had so little tyre clearance... !